# Is there any documentation for json rpc methods for supportxmr pool?

Tags: mining-pools

I am trying to write code for getblocktemplate from supportxmr pool in java. I could not figure out how to login and fetch the block info. After a lot of struggle I figured out that the method name in the JSON-RPC call should be 'login'. Is there any documentation for the methods that I can use for my JSON RPC calls for this pool?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that all API methods/calls for that pool (and all Monero pools based on [nodejs-pool](https://github.com/Snipa22/nodejs-pool)) are documented here: https://cryptonote-pool-api.restlet.io.